# filter_by over a list of JSON to check for duplicate keys

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have 2 tables, `User` and `Book`. User has a 1 to many relationship with book. A stripped back version is that a book has a title and content.

**User model**

```py
class User(db.Model):
    ''' Model to store user information '''

    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, 
    ... other columns
    books = db.relationship('Book', backref='author')
```

**Book model**

```py
class Book(db.Model):
    ''' Model to store user books '''

    __tablename__ = 'book'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    title = db.Column(db.String(120), nullable=False)
    content = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    ... other columns
```

Using SQLAlchemy, I want to ensure that a user cannot have a multiple books of the same title.

A book is generated by passing JSON to the model with a `title` and `content` keys.

If I create 2 books with the same title and then query for a specific user like so (`g.user` is an authenticated user):

```py
item=Book.query.filter_by(author_id=g.user)
```

I get the following:

```
[{'title': '"test-title"', 'content': '"test-content"'}, {'title': '"test-title"', 'content': '"test-content"'}]
```

So why, when I execute the following query, does my query return false?

```py
    exists = Book.query.filter_by(
        author_id=g.user, title=books_data['title']).scalar() is not None
```

and how can I achieve what I am looking for? If any more context is required, just let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: "I want to ensure that a user cannot have a multiple books of the same title" sounds like you need unique constraint on author_id, title pair.